# Difference between database-schema and database-design?

Tags: discussion, support

This is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043309/what-should-i-connect-when-creating-a-relationship-between-2-tables). What is the difference between those 2 tags? What should I use?

database-design

> Database design is the process of specifying the logical and/or physical parts of a database. The goal of database design is to make a representation of some "universe of discourse" - the types of facts, business rules and other requirements that the database is intended to model.

database-schema

> A description of the structure of the database - including the structure of the tables, columns, constraints, views, etc, etc... that make up the database. Normally defined in text, generally SQL in an RDBS, the schema describes the complete blueprint for the database, defining everything about ...

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation is that:

- `schema` refers to the description (documentation) of an **existing** database and
- `design` refers to the process of **creating** a database (that may not yet have a schema).

In other words `design` comes first, `schema` comes later when the `design` is done.

There may be some overlap of course as a design needs to be documented along the way, and `design` is "bigger" than just a `schema`.

Comment: A schema is a named collection of tables and can also contain views, indexes, sequences, data types, operators, and functions. So therefore the definition of a schema can be part of the process designing databases.. ;)

Answer (score -5):

"Database schema" is like a instance of space for database objects like table function. usually we are working on different database schema if we have different modules on same database and we want to make classify objects modules wise. e.g 
I have two module:
1. inventory module  table eg-> invrntory.stock_recive  ... etc
2. finance module  table eg-> finance.voucher   ... etc

"Database design" is represent the all object or all module's object's graphically representations.